# What is an elegant way to show an XOR statement

Tags: c#, java, c, syntax

What is a short and concise (and readable!) way to make sure a conditional follows the conditions:

`If a is true, then run code.`

`If b is true, then run code.`

`If both a and b is true, then do NOT run code.`

One way is Nested:

```
if (a || b)
{
    if(!(a && b))
    {
         //Code
    }
}
```

This is verbose, but perhaps more easily communicates the intention?

We can make it slightly shorter by:

```
if((a||b) && (!a&&b))
```

But that is slightly cryptic, especially if the variable names are long.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to write the above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ^ as the others have suggested, however be careful as it is also a **bitwise** exclusive or. The exact behaviour as to when it will be used for bitwise and when it will be used for logical vary by language and by data types.

For example in Java make sure that A and B are boolean types and you will be fine.

In c though if you did for ints `i` and `j`;

```
if (i ^ j) {
}
```

Then it would do a bitwise xor on i and j and then if the result of that is 0 the result would be handled as false, otherwise true.

In Java that would give you a syntax error as the result of the expression is not boolean.

Some alternatives that do work:

C/C++:

```
(!i ^ !j) 
// The ! converts i to boolean.
// It also negates the value but you don't need to reverse it back as you are comparing the relative values
```

C#/Java:

```
(A ^ B)
// Make sure A or B are boolean expressions, you will get a compile time error if they are not though.
```

Comment: +1 For understanding the difference between bitwise and logical operators. But you might want to add possible alternatives (like `(!!i ^ !!j)` for C).

Comment: +1 not only as you've noticed `^` is bitwise and not logical, but also because this solution only evaluates `i` and `j` once. The best I can do is `#define xor(a,b) (!!(a)^!!(b))`. OP: note this is a *XOR* operation, not a *NAND* operation. *NAND* can be achieved by `!(a&&b)`, but that doesn't do what you say you want.

Comment: You don't need the double !, a single will suffice. I've added C/C++/C# and Java examples and an explanation for why.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for, if I understand correctly, is the Exclusive-Or operator `^`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

"A or B but not both" is an exclusive or. You can write it as

```
if (A ^ B) {
    ...
}
```

You may also notice that it's equivalent to "A and B are different", which you can write using the `!=` operator:

```
if (A != B) {
    ...
}
```

For boolean and 0/1 values this is completely equivalent, and may be clearer sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that you want **XOR** (eXclusive OR - either a or b but not both a and b):

```
  if (a ^ b) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If a is true, then run code.
>   If b is true, then run code.
>   If both a and b is true, then do NOT run code.

This isn't NAND - this is [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate), and [`^` is the XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

```
        // When one operand is true and the other is false, exclusive-OR  
        // returns True.
        Console.WriteLine(true ^ false);
        // When both operands are false, exclusive-OR returns False.
        Console.WriteLine(false ^ false);
        // When both operands are true, exclusive-OR returns False.
        Console.WriteLine(true ^ true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need A and B to be Boolean.
Below is the code to implement NAND :

```
void main(void)
{
    bool a=true, b=false;
    if(!(a & b))
    cout<<"NAND";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NAND is simply a negation of AND, and true when AND is false, that is when:
 either a or b (or both) is false.

In C
NAND can be gotten by simply using !(a && b)

I'm not certain if this is the case in C#

Comment: NAND is _not_ when both `a` and `b` are false. One of them can be `true` (or neither, of course).